# Question about monotonic subsequence theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis

This is a homework problem.

Show that any sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a monotonic subsequence. Hint: start by supposing that is does not have a monotonically increasing subsequence.

Here is my attempt at a proof:

Proof: Let $\{p_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\{p_n\}$ has no monotonically increasing subsequence. Attempt to construct a monotonically decreasing subsequence. For the first term try $~p_1$. If $~p_1$ is such that there exists $~p_{j_1} \geq p_1$ for some $~j_1>1$, then try $~p_{j_1}$.

Having tried up to $~p_{j_i}$ and found that there exists $~p_{j_{i+1}} \geq p_{j_i}$ for some $~j_{i+1} \geq j_i$, then try $~p_{j_{i+1}}$. This process must terminate for otherwise we get a monotonically increasing subsequence: $~p_1 \leq p_{j_1} \leq ... \leq p_{j_i} \leq p_{j_{i+1}} \leq ...$

Therefore, there exists $~n_0$ such that $~p_{n_0} \geq p_k$ for all $~k$. Now let $~p_{n_0}$ be the first term of the subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $p_1=1,p_2=0$, and $p_n=2+\frac1n$ for $n\ge 3$? Then you’ll begin by picking $p_1$, since there is a later term that’s smaller, but after that you’re stuck: no term is smaller than $p_2$, so you can’t use $p_2$, but everything else is bigger than $p_1$.

Try showing instead that there must be some $n_0$ such that $p_{n_0}\ge p_k$ for all $k$, and use that as the first term of your subsequence. Then apply the same idea to the tail of the sequence consisting of all terms after $p_{n_0}$, ...

Comment: I have edited my proof. I think I have shown the existence of such a $p_{n_0}$ but now I am unsure how to choose the $(k+1)$th term.

Comment: @user151852: The same argument tells you that there is an $n_1>n_0$ such that $p_{n_1}\ge p_k$ for all $k>n_0$. By the choice of $n_0$ you know that $p_{n_0}\ge p_{n_1}$. Keep going.